# how to apply indexing of type class?

Tags: c#

I'm not really sure if I'm asking this the correct way.

I have this:

```
if (Winner[i] == LotteryArray[j][k])
                    {
                        Prediction++;
                    }
```

It's inside a series of loops and basically checks how many numbers from the "winning" row correspond with each row of the `LotteryArray` matrix. But `Winner` is made from this:

```
static ShuffledRow WinningNums()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your winning numbers are!");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
        ShuffledRow WinRow = new ShuffledRow(1, 46);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)  //this loop is to print the winning numbers
        {

            Console.Write("{0,3},", WinRow.Row[i]);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------"); //these two lines are for aesthetics 
        return WinRow;
```

Which is made from this:

```
public class ShuffledRow
{
    public static readonly Random Random = new Random();
    public readonly int[] Row;

    // Generates and shuffles some numbers
    // from min to max-1
    public ShuffledRow(int min, int max)
    {
        int count = max - min;
        Row = Enumerable.Range(min, count).ToArray();
        Shuffle(Row);
    }

    private static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
        // shuffle
        for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int j = Random.Next(i + 1);
            T temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's telling me i can't apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `ShuffledRow`

I also tried this:

```
if ((Winner<ShuffledRow[i]>) == LotteryArray[j][k])
                    {
                        Prediction++;
                    }
```

But it's giving me issues with the parenthesis for some reason.

This post is probably overly long but I didn't know how confusing it would be without including all this stuff.

So how do I fix this?

Edit: `if (Winner.Row[i] == LotteryArray[j][k])
                        {
                            Prediction++;
                        }`

this is how it's supposed to be. thank you H W

Comment: did you try `ShuffledRow.Row[i]`? (ShuffledRow is your custom class - not an array. The array you apparently want to access is the member variable `Row` inside of that class)

Comment: @HW like this `((Winner<ShuffledRow.Row[i]>) == LotteryArray[j][k])`? because that's still giving me issues with the parenthesis

Comment: what exactly does it say if you try this?

Comment: Also could you post your piece of code where you declare the `Winner` variable? Your initial question only shows how you print the winning numbers.

Comment: @HW invalid expression term `)` and then ) expected.   the parenthesis closing `Winner<ShuffledRow.Row[i]>` is the one who's an invalid expression term. and then after the final parenthesis it's telling me ) expected

Comment: @HW `ShuffledRow Winner = WinningNums();`

Comment: oh sorry.. i missread your code. Try using `Winner.Row[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `Winner<ShuffledRow[i]>` is not defined - `Winner` is an instance of your class `ShuffledRow` which is *not* a generic class!

Since you apparently want to access the Membervariable `Row` from your `ShuffledRow` class, you need to write your statement accordingly instead of trying to access the class itself:

```
ShuffledRow Winner = WinningNums();
if ((Winner.Row[i]) == LotteryArray[j][k])
                {
                    Prediction++;
                }
```